# Clipping region is not cleared by restore()

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw shape1 clipped to region1 and shape2 clipped to region2. My natural assumption was that the following would get me desired effect.

```
context.save();
context.clip(region1);
context.fill(shape1);
context.restore();

context.save();
context.clip(region2);
context.fill(shape2);
context.restore();
```

However, to my surprise, the first `restore()` doesn't cancel current clipping region. Instead, the second region is combined with the first one. That is contrary to multiple online sources which claim that `restore()` is the way to go when you're done with clipping.

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/nikitar/runvb3cu/). You can see that the second fill (blue) is clipped to region1+region2, not just region2.

Even stranger, this additive behaviour is enabled by the use of `save`/`restore` calls. If I drop them, second `clip` call is simply ignored.

So, I have two questions.

1. Is there any logic to the way clipping works in html5 canvas?
2. How can I accomplish what I originally set out to do?

Any help in figuring this out is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Always begin a new path drawing with `context.beginPath()`.

Failing to do so will cause all previous drawing commands to be re-executed along with the newly added commands.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(100, 0, 100, 300);
ctx.clip();
ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
ctx.restore();


ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(50, 50, 200, 200);
ctx.clip();
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
ctx.restore();
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been using canvas for a long time, but had no idea 'rect(...)' calls are not self-contained!